# can't access a property using <%# %>

Tags: asp.net

i was trying to hide and show a button using following code
where AllowUpdate is a property of page.
now problem is This statement never get Executed.
I have used similar code on other pages but it is unreliable many times it just fails and hides buttons even if they must not be

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="param" Text='<%$ Resources:Resources, Save%>' ID="btnsave" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn_round" OnClick="btnsave_Click" Visible="<%# AllowUpdate %>" />
```

Comment: If this approach is unreliable, you could set it in page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use the `<%# %>` syntax, you must call data bind.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1">
    <%# SomeProperty %>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind:

```
Panel1.DataBind();
```

Alternatively, use the `<%= %>` syntax.

```
<%= SomeProperty %>
```

or as Cal279 points out in the comments, you can set it in your code behind on some event, such as `Page_Load`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       Butbtnsaveon1.Visible = AllowUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried `btnsave.DataBind();` and it works...
and <%= %> can't be used on server controls.

However i will prefer to use code behind...